# sympy.solve() doesn't give one of the solutions with LambertW

Tags: python, sympy, solver, inverse

**Background:**
I am trying to implement a function doing an [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). I use [sympy](/questions/tagged/sympy) for calculating [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) and getting its inverse function. While for some simple [PDFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) I get correct results, for a PDF which CDF's inverse function includes [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), results are wrong.

**Example:**
Consider following example CDF:

```py
import sympy as sym

y = sym.Symbol('y')
cdf = (-y - 1) * sym.exp(-y) + 1  # derived from `pdf = x * sym.exp(-x)`
sym.plot(cdf, (y, -1, 5))
```

[image]
Now calculating inverse of this function:

```py
x = sym.Symbol('x')
inverse = sym.solve(sym.Eq(x, cdf), y)
print(inverse)
```

Output:

```py
[-LambertW((x - 1)*exp(-1)) - 1]
```

This, in fact, is only a left branch of negative y's of a given CDF:

```py
sym.plot(inverse[0], (x, -0.5, 1))
```

[image]

**Question:**
How can I get the right branch for positive y's of a given CDF?

**What I tried:**

1. Specifying `x` and `y` to be only positive:

   ```py
   x = sym.Symbol('x', positive=True)
   y = sym.Symbol('y', positive=True)
   ```

   This doesn't have any effect, even for the first CDF plot.
2. Making CDF a [`Piecewise`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#piecewise) function:

   ```py
   cdf = sym.Piecewise((0, y < 0),
                       ((-y - 1) * sym.exp(-y) + 1, True))
   ```

   Again no effect. Strange thing here is that on another computer plotting this function gave a proper graph with zero for negative y's, but solving for a positive y's branch doesn't work anywhere. (Different versions? I also had to specify `adaptive=False` to [`sympy.plot`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#plotting-function-reference) to make it work there.)
3. Using [`sympy.solveset`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#module-sympy.solvers.solveset) instead of [`sympy.solve`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#module-sympy.solvers):
   This just gives a useless `ConditionSet(y, Eq(x*exp(y) + y - exp(y) + 1, 0), Complexes(S.Reals x S.Reals, False))` as a result. Apparently, `solveset` still doesn't know how to deal with [`LambertW`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/powers.html#lambert-w-function) functions. From the docs:

   > When cases which are not solved or can only be solved incompletely, a
   >   `ConditionSet` is used and acts as an unevaluated solveset object. <...>
   >   There are still a few things `solveset` can’t do, which the old `solve`
   >   can, such as solving non linear multivariate & LambertW type
   >   equations.

Is it a bug or am I missing something? Is there any workaround to get the desired result?

Comment: A longstanding [issue with solve](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/4333). Problems like this is what motivated the development of `solveset`, but it has not reached feature parity with solve, in particular [LambertW solutions are not implemented in solveset](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12243).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inverse produced by sympy is almost correct. The problem lies in the fact that the LambertW function has multiple branches over the domain (-1/e, 0). By default, it uses the upper branch, however for your problem you require the lower branch. The lower branch can be accessed by passing in a second argument to LambertW with a value of -1.

```
inverse = -sym.LambertW((x - 1)*sym.exp(-1), -1) - 1
sym.plot(inverse, (x, 0, 0.999))
```

Gives

[image]